# How to memory profile in Java?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

I'm still learning the ropes of Java so sorry if there's a obvious answer to this. I have a program that is taking a ton of memory and I want to figure a way to reduce its usage, but after reading many SO questions I have the idea that I need to prove where the problem is before I start optimizing it.

So here's what I did, I added a break point to the start of my program and ran it, then I started visualVM and had it profile the memory(I also did the same thing in netbeans just to compare the results and they are the same).   My problem is I don't know how to read them, I got the highest area just saying `char[]` and I can't see any code or anything(which makes sense because visualvm is connecting to the jvm and can't see my source, but netbeans also does not show me the source as it does when doing cpu profiling).

Basically what I want to know is which variable(and hopefully more details like in which method) all the memory is being used so I can focus on working there.  Is there a easy way to do this? I right now I am using eclipse and java to develop(and installed visualVM and netbeans specifically for profiling but am willing to install anything else that you feel gets this job done).

EDIT: Ideally, I'm looking for something that will take all my objects and sort them by size(so I can see which one is hogging memory). Currently it returns generic information such as string[] or int[] but I want to know which object its referring to so I can work on getting its size more optimized.

Comment: I use a profiler which shows me where objects are being allocated as well. I don't know if VisualVM can do this, but its very useful. The one I use is YourKit, but its not free (but you can get an eval license)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I actually read an answer you wrote a while ago where you mentioned yourkit was your first choice to use, I did look it up(since your advice is always awesome) but yes its a bit expensive and I'm just learning.

Comment: without using something that instruments your code no analyser is going to be able to point out which instance == what you called a reference in your source.

Answer (score 27):

**Strings are problematic**

Basically in Java, `String` references ( things that use `char[]` behind the scenes ) will dominate most *business* applications memory wise. How they are created determines how much memory they consume in the JVM.

Just because they are so fundamental to most business applications as a data type, and they are one of the most memory hungry as well. This isn't just a Java thing, `String` data types take up lots of memory in pretty much every language and run time library, because at the least they are just arrays of 1 byte per character or at the worse ( Unicode ) they are arrays of multiple bytes per character.

Once when profiling CPU usage on a web app that also had an Oracle JDBC dependency I discovered that `StringBuffer.append()` dominated the CPU cycles by many orders of magnitude over all other method calls **combined**, much less any other single method call. The JDBC driver did lots and lots of `String` manipulation, kind of the trade off of using `PreparedStatements` for everything.

**What you are concerned about you can't control, not directly anyway**

What you should focus on is what in in your control, which is making sure you don't hold on to references longer than you need to, and that you are not duplicating things unnecessarily. The garbage collection routines in Java are highly optimized, and if you learn how their algorithms work, you can make sure your program behaves in the optimal way for those algorithms to work.

**Java Heap Memory isn't like manually managed memory in other languages, those rules don't apply**

What are considered *memory leaks* in other languages aren't the same thing/root cause as in Java with its garbage collection system.

Most likely in Java memory isn't consumed by one single uber-object that is leaking ( dangling reference in other environments ).

It is most likely lots of smaller allocations because of `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` objects not sized appropriately on first instantantations and then having to automatically grow the `char[]` arrays to hold subsequent `append()` calls.

These intermediate objects may be held around longer than expected by the garbage collector because of the scope they are in and lots of other things that can vary at run time.

**EXAMPLE:** the garbage collector may decide that there are candidates, but because it considers that there is plenty of memory still to be had that it might be too expensive time wise to flush them out at that point in time, and it will wait until memory pressure gets higher.

The garbage collector is really good now, but it isn't magic, if you are doing degenerate things, it will cause it to not work optimally. There is lots of documentation on the internet about the garbage collector settings for all the versions of the JVMs.

These un-referenced objects may just have not reached the time that the garbage collector thinks it needs them to for them to be expunged from memory, or there could be references to them held by some other object ( `List` ) for example that you don't realize still points to that object. This is what is most commonly referred to as a *leak* in Java, which is a reference leak more specifically.

**EXAMPLE:** If you know you need to build a 4K `String` using a `StringBuilder` create it with `new StringBuilder(4096);` not the default, which is like 32 and will immediately start creating garbage that can represent many times what you think the object should be size wise.

You can discover how many of what types of objects are instantiated with VisualVM, this will tell you what you need to know. There isn't going to be one big flashing light that points at a single instance of a single class that says, "This is the big memory consumer!", that is unless there is only one instance of some `char[]` that you are reading some massive file into, and this is not possible either, because lots of other classes use `char[]` internally; and then you pretty much knew that already.

**I don't see any mention of `OutOfMemoryError`**

You probably don't have a problem in your code, the garbage collection system just might not be getting put under enough pressure to kick in and deallocate objects that you *think* it should be cleaning up. What **you think** is a problem probably isn't, not unless your program is crashing with `OutOfMemoryError`. This isn't C, C++, Objective-C, or any other manual memory management language / runtime. You don't get to decide what is in memory or not at the detail level you are expecting you should be able to.

Answer (score 13):

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), you can take go to the heap walker and activate the biggest objects view. You will see the objects the retain most memory. "Retained" memory is the memory that would be freed by the garbage collector if you removed the object.

You can then open the object nodes to see the reference tree of the retained objects. Here's a screen shot of the biggest object view:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend capturing heap dumps and using a tool like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) that lets you analyze them. There are many [tutorials](http://scn.sap.com/people/krum.tsvetkov/blog/2007/07/02/finding-memory-leaks-with-sap-memory-analyzer) available. It provides a view of the [dominator tree](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/concepts/dominatortree.html) to provide insight into the relationships between the objects on the heap. Specifically for what you mentioned, the "path to GC roots" feature of MAT will tell you where the majority of those char[], String[] and int[] objects are being referenced. JVisualVM can also be useful in identifying leaks and allocations, particularly by using snapshots with allocation stack traces. There are quite a few [walk-throughs of the process](http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html) of getting the snapshots and comparing them to find the allocation point.

Answer (score 4):

Java JDK comes with **JVisualVM** under bin folder, once your application server (for example is running) you can run visualvm and connect it to your localhost, which will provide you memory allocation and enable you to perform heap dump

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use visualVM to check your memory usage, it focuses on the data, not the methods. Maybe your big char[] data is caused by many String values? Unless you are using recursion, the data will not be from local variables. So you can focus on the methods that insert elements into large data structures. To find out what precise statements cause your "memory leakage", I suggest you additionally

- read [Josh Bloch's Effective Java Item 6: (Eliminate obsolete object references)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
- use a logging framework an log instance creations on the highest verbosity level.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two distinct approaches to analyse Java code to gain an understanding of its memory allocation profile. If you're trying to measure the impact of a specific, small section of code – say you want to compare two alternative implementations in order to decide which one gives better runtime performance – you would use a microbenchmarking tool such as [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

While you can pause the running program, the JVM is a sophisticated runtime that performs a variety of housekeeping tasks and it's really hard to get a "point in time" snapshot and an accurate reading of the "level of memory usage". It might allocate/free memory at a rate that does not directly reflect the behaviour of the running Java program. Similarly, performing a Java object heap dump does not fully capture the low-level machine specific memory layout that dictates the actual memory footprint, as this could depend on the machine architecture, JVM version, and other runtime factors.

Tools like JMH get around this by repeatedly running a small section of code, and observing a long-running average of memory allocations across a number of invocations. E.g. in the [GC profiling sample JMH benchmark](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/b6f87aa2a687/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_35_Profilers.java) the derived `*·gc.alloc.rate.norm` metric gives a reasonably accurate per-invocation normalised memory cost.

In the more general case, you can attach a profiler to a running application and get JVM-level metrics, or perform a heap dump for offline analysis. Some commonly used tools for profiling full applications are [Async Profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) and the newly open-sourced [Java Flight Recorder in conjunction with Java Mission Control](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/java-flight-recorder-and-jfr-event-streaming-in-java-14) to visualise results.